# AWS Cognito update email using JavaScript 3 SDK AdminUpdateUserAttributesCommand

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm attempting to update a cognito user's email via JavaScript 3 SDK AdminUpdateUserAttributesCommand.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/classes/adminupdateuserattributescommand.html

It works fine with other attributes like "given_name" and "family_name", but email just doesn't update.  No errors thrown.  200 response.

"QQQ" injected in a few places to prevent any private data from being exposed.

```
import { APIGatewayEvent, APIGatewayProxyResult } from "aws-lambda";
import {
  AdminUpdateUserAttributesCommand,
  AdminUpdateUserAttributesCommandInput,
  CognitoIdentityProviderClient,
} from "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider";
export const index = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
});

const userPool = process.env.AUTH_QQQ_USERPOOLID || "us-east-2_QQQ";

export const handler = async (
  event: APIGatewayEvent
): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
  let result: any = "";
  if (event?.body) {
    const request = JSON.parse(event.body);
    console.log("~~~ request: ", request);
    const userName = "QQQ-f263-4a3e-85be-QQQ"; // temporarily hard-coded to eliminate chance of error
    const attributes = [
      {
        Name: "email", // "given_name" and "family_name" update without issue
        Value: "user1@gmail.com", // temporarily hard-coded
      },
    ];
    console.log("~~~ userPool: ", userPool);
    console.log("~~~ userName: ", userName);
    console.log("~~~ attributes: ", attributes);
    const command = new AdminUpdateUserAttributesCommand({
      UserPoolId: userPool,
      Username: userName,
      UserAttributes: attributes,
    } as AdminUpdateUserAttributesCommandInput);
    const response = await index.send(command);
    console.log("~~~ response: " + JSON.stringify(response));
    result = response;
  } else {
    console.error("userUpdate without body. event: " + JSON.stringify(event));
  }

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
    },
    body: result.toString(),
  };
};
```

console.log("~~~ response: " + JSON.stringify(response))

```
{
  "$metadata": {
    "httpStatusCode": 200,
      "requestId": "QQQ-70f4-4896-a48d-0ac55872f4b2",
      "attempts": 1,
      "totalRetryDelay": 0
  }
}
```

I can change email directly in the console so I know it's mutable.

The userpool is setup to allow sign-in using email address.  Is that the issue?  Is there a work-around?

```
Alias attributes used to sign in: Email
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out.  Verification was preventing it from updating, but was completely transparent.  Updating fields set to require verification requires a user enter the verification code somewhere.  I'm not sure how I would work that into my UI flow.  Alternatively you can send email_verified=true as described in the documentation here and entering the verification code is not needed:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/admin-update-user-attributes.html#options

> If your user pool requires verification before Amazon Cognito updates an attribute value that you specify in this request, Amazon Cognito doesn’t immediately update the value of that attribute. After your user receives and responds to a verification message to verify the new value, Amazon Cognito updates the attribute value. Your user can sign in and receive messages with the original attribute value until they verify the new value.

> To update the value of an attribute that requires verification in the same API request, include the email_verified or phone_number_verified attribute, with a value of true . If you set the email_verified or phone_number_verified value for an email or phone_number attribute that requires verification to true , Amazon Cognito doesn’t send a verification message to your user.

Here's the code update that solved the issue:

```
const attributes = [
  {
    Name: "email", // "given_name" and "family_name" update without issue
    Value: "user1@gmail.com", // temporarily hard-coded
  },
  //  update 
  {
    Name: "email_verified",
    Value: "true", // NOTE: this must be a string, not a boolean
  },
];
```

Comment: The `Value` needing to be a string probably saved me a number of hours of frustration today.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the verification yourself, but you may want to consider allowing Cognito to verify it for you which is probably what you would want instead.
I had the same issue but since the email was part of the authentication, I wanted to ensure the user verified the new email first before allowing the email to be changed.
You can use the [VerifyUserAttribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/classes/verifyuserattributecommand.html) API as part of the @aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider

If the user is updating their email, you can add a verification code field to your UI and have the user enter it in once they receive the email.  You can then call this API which will change the email AND mark it as verified which is the more secure/safer approach.

Here is an Angular snippet which takes in the verification code from the UI:

```
 /**
   * Verifies a user attribute
   * @description Uses the AWS Javascript SDK V3
   * @see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-cognito-identity-provider/classes/verifyuserattributecommand.html
   */
  public async verifyUserAttribute(attributeName: string, verificationCode: string) {
    console.log(`verifyUserAttribute(${attributeName}, ${verificationCode})`);
    const clientConfig: CognitoIdentityProviderClientConfig = {
      region: environment.region
    };
    const client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient(clientConfig);

    const input: VerifyUserAttributeRequest = { // VerifyUserAttributeRequest
      AccessToken: this.getAccessToken(), // required
      AttributeName: attributeName, // required
      Code: verificationCode, // required
    };

    const command = new VerifyUserAttributeCommand(input);

    try {
      const data: VerifyUserAttributeCommandOutput = await client.send(command);
      console.log('data: ', data);
      super.displaySnackBar('Verification Successful!' + data);
      // process data.
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('error from call:', error);
      super.displaySnackBar('Verification Failed!');
      // error handling.
    }

  }
```